# Pngs are blank when using convert

Tags: imagick, macos-catalina, libpng

The following is giving me a blank image of the expected size:

```
magick convert a.png b.png -compose difference -composite out.png
```

However, I can produce the correct output as a jpg:

```
magick convert a.png b.png -compose difference -composite out.jpg
```

I then tried to convert this to a png and it works fine:

```
magick convert out.jpg out.png
```

Why is the first command giving me a blank image and how might I fix the problem?

```
Libpng version 1.6.37. 


Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-8 Q16 x86_64 2021-04-17 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

**UPDATE:**

Bmp is also blank:

magick convert a.png b.png -compose difference -composite out.bmp

And this also works for jpg but not png:

```
composite -compose difference a.png b.png out.png
```

And this is what I see when running verbose:

```
a.png PNG 500x700 500x700+0+0 8-bit sRGB 125771B 0.030u 0:00.016
b.png PNG 500x700 500x700+0+0 8-bit sRGB 90207B 0.020u 0:00.012
a.png=>b.png PNG 500x700 500x700+0+0 8-bit sRGB 90207B 0.450u 0:00.084
```

This is working and is giving my the required output:

```
composite -verbose -compose minus a.png b.png out.png
```

Comment: In Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert. That may not help, however.

Comment: Is your /tmp directory full?

Comment: Can you post a.png and b.png?

Comment: Might it just be your viewer?

Comment: I have seen commands that produce blank PNGs be fixed by adding `-channel rgb`.